# mysql Trigger On insert

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

whats wrong with my syntax?

```
CREATE 
    TRIGGER db_dhruniversity.trigger1
    AFTER INSERT
    ON jos_dhruprofile
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE jos_users 
  SET jos_users.department = jos_dhruprofile.department 
  WHERE jos_users.id = jos_dhruprofile.uid
END
```

Comment: can you show the compilation error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no delimiters in it:

```
DELIMITER ||

CREATE 
    TRIGGER db_dhruniversity.trigger1
    AFTER INSERT
    ON jos_dhruprofile
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE jos_users 
  SET jos_users.department = NEW.department 
  WHERE jos_users.id = NEW.uid;
END ||

DELIMITER;
```

Comment: perhaps tell us what you want to achieve then?

Comment: I have two tables, one is called 

userprofile  the other is called users

Everytime a new record is inserted into userprofile I want to update the table 'users' 

this a mockup structure

table -userprfile  
id
uid
name
department

table-users
id
name 
email
department  ( want to update this field on every insert from the userprofiletable)

As now  , the table userprofile matches users on uid = id    , there is no contratins, or foreign keys, which I probably would need, not sure,,,

How can I do this.? Thanks in advance.....

Comment: If you're running this from phpMyAdmin sl box, note that there's a separate field for delimiter below. In such case just put `||` there and omit `DELIMITER` statements from the SQL above

Answer (score 4):

The syntax should be as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$  /* if you're not using an editor, you must change the delimiter*/

CREATE 
    TRIGGER ai_jos_dhruprofile_each
    AFTER INSERT
    ON jos_dhruprofile
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE jos_users 
  SET jos_users.department = NEW.department 
  WHERE jos_users.id = NEW.uid;  /*<<<--- ; after every stament */
END $$   /* changed delimiter after the end */

DELIMITER ; /*make sure you set the delimiter back to the default*/
```

**Note on the naming scheme for triggers**
I'd recommend naming your trigger `ai` (meaning `after insert`) so you know when it fires on which table, rather than a meaningless name like: `db_dhruniversity.trigger1`.
I always use **[a/b]+[d/i/u]_tablename_each** as the triggername, that way I always know when the triggers fires <kbd>(before/after)</kbd> for which event <kbd>(insert/delete/update)</kbd> and on which table.

It's also good practise to document that the trigger fires on `each` row, hence the `each` on the end of the trigger name.

*Note that MySQL does not support triggers that fire once per statement **yet** (But that might change in future).*